# Why Guice cannot find my implementation in Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

My controller code have a trait and a implementation of that trait which also extends `CustomeExecutionContext`, but Guice cannot find my implementation.

The controller code:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import com.ntu.rule._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

trait RuleValidationExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext

class RuleValidationExecutionContextImpl @Inject()(system: ActorSystem)
  extends CustomExecutionContext(system, "rule-validation-context") with RuleValidationExecutionContext

@Singleton
class RulesController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents,
                                ruleValidationExecutionContext: RuleValidationExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def validate() = Action(parse.json).async { implicit request: Request[JsValue] =>
    Future {
      val rule = (request.body \ "rule").as[String]
      val parsedRule = RuleUtils.parseRules(rule)
      val (isSuccess, message) = RuleUtils.validate(parsedRule)
      Ok(Json.parse(
        s"""
           |{"success": $isSuccess, "message": "$message"}
      """.stripMargin))
    }(ruleValidationExecutionContext)
  }
}
```

And application.conf:

```
rule-validation-context {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 20.0
    parallelism-max = 200
  }
}
```

When I request the action, it shows:

```
1 error]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:186)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.play$core$server$AkkaHttpServer$$modelConversion(AkkaHttpServer.scala:183)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.play$core$server$AkkaHttpServer$$handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:189)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$5.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$5.apply(AkkaHttpServer.scala:106)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$24.onPush(Ops.scala:1191)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:512)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:475)
        at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:371)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for controllers.RuleValidationExecutionContext was bound.
  while locating controllers.RuleValidationExecutionContext
    for the 2nd parameter of controllers.RulesController.<init>(RulesController.scala:19)
  while locating controllers.RulesController
    for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:38)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for the 1st parameter of play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:222)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for the 6th parameter of play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:236)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:235)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application
```

But the implementation is in the controller code as above, why Guice cannot find it??
My Scala version is 2.11.11, Play Framework version is 2.6.11

Answer (score 2):

I guess the reason is Guice needs more information on which instance should be instantiated for the parameter of type `ruleValidationExecutionContext`. although you add `@inject` annotation to the class `RuleValidationExecutionContextImpl`, it is not the same type as `ruleValidationExecutionContext`. you can do

1. add another annotation

   @ImplementedBy(classOf[RuleValidationExecutionContextImpl])
   trait RuleValidationExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext
   //blah blah...

or

2. add something like below to your `module.scala`

```

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class Module extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[RuleValidationExecutionContext])
      .to(classOf[RuleValidationExecutionContextImpl])
  }
}
```

```

Please refer to [this link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Providing-custom-bindings)